# Menu Management

Tags: 7, routes

I am trying to make menu management easy for my clients in Drupal 7.

1. How can I make it so that clients can move links on the menu but cannot delete the top level menu? For example, if the top level menu item is "Products", how can I make it so that the clients cannot delete the menu item "Products" (and even the node itself) but they can reorder the children?
2. Let's say I have a main menu item called "Products" and under it I have "Phones". How can I make it so that if a node "Phones" has children under it on the menu, that it can not be deleted. Because right now, if the client deletes "Phones", all of its menu children are automatically moved up to the same level that the other product categories were on i.e. "Televisions", "Computers", etc.

Comment: Hello JM01, and welcome on _Drupal Answers_. You tagged this question with _nodes_, but I don't understand which is the relationship between the menu you are describing, and nodes. May you explain that in your question?

Comment: When I add a basic page, it creates a node. I have the option to "Provide a menu link" under "Menu Settings" when I edit the node. I can also delete the node, and that is where the trouble begins with the menu.

Comment: You can create a menu without to create a node. Drupal gives you the possibility of creating a menu item while creating a node, but those "entities" are not related to each other.

Answer (score 1):

If using Drupal 6 is a possibility, these 2 modules would help:

[Menu Parent](http://drupal.org/project/menu_parent)

[Menu Admin per Menu](http://drupal.org/project/menu_admin_per_menu)

Comment: Menu Admin per Menu is a step in the right direction because it restricts access to only certain menus. However, the client can still move top level menu items around which can cause major problems with the CSS, main navigation, and breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

From what little I know, I think this is tricky to do in Drupal 7. It does look like there is some work going on with the [workbench access](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_access) module to allow better integration for menus: http://drupal.org/node/1101638.

Some other things to explore might be the [book](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/book) module (comes with drupal core), or even fudging with different content types (maybe make one for "landing pages" which the editor cannot delete, and one for "sub-page" which they can delete... I have never tried this though). Also potentially [organic groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) with [organic groups menu](http://drupal.org/project/og_menu) (this, as a lot of modules is in dev, and I'm not sure how well it works).

Let us know if you come to a solution, I would be interested in knowing as well.